# Capture a regex in a if condition

Tags: python, regex, match

I would like to capture the match of my regex directly in my if condition. I know it was possible in PHP, but I don't know how to do it in a Pythonic way.
So I run it twice and it's not sexy at all...

```
str = 'Test string 178-126-587-0 with a match'
if re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]', str) != []:
    match = re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]', str)[0]
```

Comment: so you need only the 1st match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do in-line variable assignment while using a conditional construct in Python, you need to leverage a temp variable. In your case, `re.search` would do as you are taking the first element anyway and there is no captured group:

```
match_ = re.search(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]', str_)
if match_:
    match = match_.group()
```

---

Regarding your original example, empty list is falsey in Python, so:

```
if not some_list:
    # Do stuffs
```

would do.

Comment: Thanks heemayl, but I don't get the ".group()" thing. Why not match[0] since there is only one match using search()?

Comment: @Maxime  Unlike `re.findall`, `re.search` returns a match object, not a list. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution with the `:=` operator reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881906/6693076):

```
str = 'Test string 178-126-587-0 with a match'
if (match := re.search(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]', str)):
    match = match.group()
```